# find distance between contours/objects in opencv

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, syntax, opencv

I have found the contours using cvfindcontour, and, now I want to access first and second contour and find the euclidean distance between them. Could anybody help me with its code?

```
CvPoint *contourPoint, *contourPoint2;
contourPoint = (CvPoint *)CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint,contours,1);
contourPoint2 = (CvPoint *)CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint,contours,2);
double dis = sqrt(double((contourPoint->x - contourPoint2->x) * (contourPoint->x - contourPoint2->x) + (contourPoint->y - contourPoint2->y) * (contourPoint->y - contourPoint2->y)) );
```

is it the correct way?

Comment: Read first C++ manuals, then OpenCV docs. Your question denotes total lack of effort from you.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I should have done that, but I was not given enough time to learn stuff thoroughly because of the early deadline. But, I will go through in detail after the deadline. Will you please help me for now?

Comment: since contour1 and contour2 are pointers, you need to write at least `contour1->x - contour2->x` and so on...

Comment: i have edited the code, tell me, if this is the correct way?

Comment: I don't know the OpenCV API. You need to check the definition of CvPoint yourself to answer that. If it is like `typedef struct _CvPoint{double x; double y; \* and morestuff *\} CvPoint;` then yes. Check your header files... and read more about the OpenCV structures.

Comment: Two contours may have different distances between them depending on the points between which you are measuring the distance. At first glance your code seems correct - have you tried compiling it and running?

Comment: I have tried it, it doesnot give any errors, but it does not display the correct results as well. I actually want to find the distance between centroids, and I have found centroids as well using cvmoments, but it is difficult to find distance between centroids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [cvMoments](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvmoments#void%20cvMoments%28const%20CvArr%2a%20array,%20CvMoments%2a%20moments,%20int%20binary%29) to compute the centroid of each contour, and then compute the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the two centroids. [Here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=2275.0) is a post on openframeworks about it. [Here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/18499) is a post from the opencv mailing-list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The distance between their centroids can be very large while in the same time the distance between borders can be very small.